Scala Test squashing nested suites future asserts
I'm running nested test suites that call futures, any exceptions or assertions from inside a transform are being ignored by the test handler.
class TestManager extends AsyncFlatSpec {

  val reporter: Reporter = new Reporter() {
    override def apply(e: Event): Unit = {}
  }

  val suite = new NestedSuite()
  suite.testNames.foreach(test => it should test in {
    val result = suite.run(Some(test), Args(reporter))
    log.info("{}",result.succeeds())
    assert(result.succeeds())
  })

}

class NestedSuite extends AsyncFlatSpec {

  it should "be false" in {
    def exampleFunction: Future[Boolean] = {
      Thread.sleep(50)
      Future.successful(false)
    }
    exampleFunction.transformWith { 
      case Success(v) => assert(v)
      case Failure(ex) => assert(false)
    }
  }

  it should "also be false" in {
    def exampleFunction: Future[Boolean] = {
      Thread.sleep(50)
      Future.failed(makeSystemException(result_exception))
    }
    exampleFunction.transformWith { _ =>
      throw makeSystemException(result_exception)
    }
  }

}


These tests always succeed. How do I properly report the exception or a false asserts from the returning future?
